# How to create a msi by using cx_freeze which will accept command line input

Tags: python, windows-installer, cx-freeze

let's say I have an msi "foo.msi" 
If I want to pass an option like

```
    foo.msi <option>
```

Is it possible? If so how can I do this?
I am using cx_freeze to create msi

Comment: what is the point of passing an option ? I never saw that...

Comment: Have you tried `sys.argv`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSIs are executed by Msiexec.exe so the only command-line options that are possible are those supported by Msiexec.exe: [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx).